# YYYY-MM column type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.6

I need to a value associated to a month and a user in a table. And I want to perform queries on it. I don't know if there is a column data type for this type of need. If not, should I:

- Create a string field and build year-month concatenation (2017-01)
- Create a int field and build year-month concatenation (201701)
- Create two columns (one year and one month)
- Create a date column at the beginning of the month (2017-01-01 00:00:00)
- Something else?

The objective is to run queries like (pseudo-SQL):

```
SELECT val FROM t WHERE year_month = THIS_YEAR_MONTH and user_id='adc1-23...';
```

Comment: Use a date column, and add a date_resolution column, which indicates the resolution of that date. Then do your date math based on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest not thinking too hard about the problem and just using the first date/time of the month.  Postgres has plenty of date-specific functions -- from `date_trunc()` to `age()` to `+ interval` -- to support dates.

You can readily convert them to the format you want, get the difference between two values, and so on.

If you phrase your query as:

```
where year_month = date_trunc('month', now()) and user_id = 'adc1-23...'
```

Then it can readily take advantage of an index on `(user_id, year_month)` or `(year_month, user_id)`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in display values in YYYY-MM formt you can use to_char(your_datatime_colum,'YYYY-MM')

example:

```
SELECT to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM') as year_month
```

Answer (score 0):

The column type should be DATE in date_column, and extract function is the way to go in the query for the requirements that you listed:

```
SELECT to_char(date_column,'YYYY_MM') as year_month, to_char(now(),'Month yyyy') as year_month2, extract(MONTH from now()) as current_month,
           concat('Q', extract(QUARTER from now())) as current_quarter, extract(YEAR from now()) as current_year
```

I have put example column named date_column and now()function if you want to test before you query.
More documentation on:
[Postgres extract function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: Have you posted your answer in the wrong thread? The question was asked in 2017 and got a good answer that got accepted. Your answer on the other hand doesn't address what is being asked here.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I feel my explanation and approach is different and more proper

Comment: By not answering the question? The question is how to store a month. Your answer is there are several ways to get years, months and quarters from a date column or a timestamp. You see that this doesn't answer the question. This is why I supposed you may have posted your answer in a wrong thread and wanted to answer an entirely different request. I suggest you delete this answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I do not get your point. I have stated that storing the value should be in columnt type DATE, and in query he can use EXTRACT function. This is not in any of other answers, which suggest to_char() and date_trunc().

Comment: You obviously *got* my point, because you added a remark to your answer that they should use a date column for the month. Gordon Linoff went further in his accepted answer in 2017 by saying it should be the first of the month getting stored. He mentions how to query the data then and still benefit from an index on the date column thus, as we don't have to apply any function on the column. So, yes, now with your addition you are finally answering the question. Your suggestion to store whatever date and use `EXTRACT` is a valid approach, but Gordon's suggestion is better performancewise.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ok, at least you should not downgrade the answer and we have it in record as an option. That was my intention and I improved to be more clear regarding your suggestions